# Do people who use the Death Note become Shinigami themselves?

Tags: death-note

In both the Death Note manga and anime, it is stated multiple times by Ryuk that once you use the Death Note, a human can go to neither Heaven nor Hell.

However, it is hinted in an additional movie that encompasses part of the anime that Light was reincarnated as a Shinigami.

Is it then possible to say, that any humans that use the Death Note do not go to Heaven nor Hell because they go to the Shinigami Realm?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No.

Humans who die don't go to Heaven or Hell (because neither exists).

They go to [Mu](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Mu) (Which means, nothing).

> **Death Note, Volume 12**, page *188*, has these two rules in regards to
>   "Mu": "All humans will, without exception, eventually die." Also,
>   "After they die, the place they go is MU (Nothingness)."

---

Basically, there's nothing after death. Shinigami are a different species.

Comment: On the other hand, it's worth noting that every single person who has used the Death Note has died.

Comment: That's also stated by Ryuk. The fate of every Death Note user is the same. The Shinigami originally owning the Death Note will write their down in the Death Note, and they will die. There is an exception to that rule. Misa Misa didn't die at the end of the series.

Comment: It depends on which ending you go with.  I believe the anime she lived, whereas in the manga, it is at least stated that she died.

Comment: Can you please cite your answer?

Comment: @atlantiza cited. :P Madara is going senile..

Comment: there be spoilers here

Comment: you probably shouldnt go here anyway if you havent watched the full anime as this site will always contain spoilers :)

Comment: They go to MU? Manchester United? LOL